# Have to compare equality of 5 numbers and choose best of 3 in case in C

Tags: equality

I have a situation where i have to write a code to compare 5 integers to see which ones are equal and choose atleast 3 equal numbers of the 5 nrs. More than:-

e.g.

```
a=0,b=0,c=0,d=2,c=3
 then Valid_nr=0,
a=6,b=0,c=6,d=6,c=6
 then Valid_nr=6,
a=8,b=8,c=8,d=8,c=8
 then Valid_nr=8
```

Please suggest me some logic because this seems to be very confusing to write a short and efficient code to achieve this..

Comment: Create an array of the numbers, 1st sort the numbers and then compare i with i+1

Comment: But den i have to choose atleast 3 numbers which are equal ?

Answer (score 0):

Example written in C#:

```
 class Program
    {
        static List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        static int NumOfequals = 1;
        static int ValidNUmber;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                int input;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (i+1).ToString() + "and press enter");
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out input))
                {
                    numbers.Add(input);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not an integer");
                }
            }

            numbers.Sort();
            for (int i=0;i<numbers.Count;i++)
            {
                if (i<numbers.Count-1)
                {
                    if (numbers[i]==numbers[i+1])
                    {
                        NumOfequals++;
                        ValidNumber=numbers[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (NumOfequals < 3)
                       {
                        NumOfequals = 1;
                        ValidNumber=-1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("number of equal numbers is " + NumOfequals.ToString()+" and the valid number is:"+ValidNumber.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you a function in C that generalize the problem in your question, `equalities()` compares the elements of an array of int and return the maximum number of equalities. A pointer to an int is passed too to store the value of the repeted number. You can easily specialize this function for your problem or use it as it is and check if the returned value is >= 3 only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int equalities( int *nums, int n, int *x ) {
    int * vals = malloc(n * sizeof(int)); 
    int * reps = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < n && reps[j] != 0 && vals[j] != nums[i]; ++j );
        if ( j != 0 && reps[j] == reps[0]) { // new max
            vals[j] = vals[0];
            vals[0] = nums[i];
            ++reps[0];
        } else {
            vals[j] = nums[i];
            ++reps[j];
        }
    }
    *x = vals[0];
    int rep = reps[0];
    free(vals);
    free(reps);
    return rep;
}

int main(void) {
    int test1[] = { 1, 4, 2, 4, 4 };
    int test2[] = { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 };
    int test3[] = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5 };
    int test4[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    int test5[] = { 5, 5, 0, 5, 0 };

    int y = -1;
    int r = equalities(test1,5,&y);
    printf("Repetitions: %d, Number: %d\n",r,y);
    r = equalities(test2,5,&y);
    printf("Repetitions: %d, Number: %d\n",r,y);
    r = equalities(test3,5,&y);
    printf("Repetitions: %d, Number: %d\n",r,y);
    r = equalities(test4,5,&y);
    printf("Repetitions: %d, Number: %d\n",r,y);
    r = equalities(test5,5,&y);
    printf("Repetitions: %d, Number: %d\n",r,y);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test `main()` is:

```
Repetitions: 3, Number: 4
Repetitions: 4, Number: 0
Repetitions: 1, Number: 1
Repetitions: 5, Number: 1
Repetitions: 3, Number: 5
```